# How to know changes in color with selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Am working on this website : [here](https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/tts-demo/self-service/home) , when u insert a text in the text-area, and click on play button

it gonna take a while then you hear the audio, what i did notice is when the audio is playing the

border around the text-area turns to blue.

what i want to know: is there any way to detect that using selenium on python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is actually the CSS property "outline".

The code below clicks the button and prints the outline, which is "rgb(15, 97, 254) solid 2px".

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def scrape_products():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

    browser.get("https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/tts-demo/self-service/home")
    time.sleep(2)

    play = browser.find_element_by_id('btn')
    play.click()
    time.sleep(10)

    textarea = browser.find_element_by_id('text-area')
    outline = textarea.value_of_css_property('outline')

    print(outline)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scrape_products()
```